# Is there a way to invoke a .NET Framework offline installation?

Tags: c#, .net, installation

I'm making a test application for learning purposes. It's targetted for the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

I created a new Windows XP virtual machine that doesn't have a .NET Framework installed. Ideally I'd like to create a setup project for my little application and bundle that with the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile. I **do not** want my end users to download anything. This application should be installable offline without the need for an internet connection

So the end user would click my created Setup.exe and it would invoke the setup menu for the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: do you have visual studio?  if so, did you look in the project settings under deployment?

Comment: @Gabriel: This is the only project Settings I can find and I'm sure this isn't what you mean: http://imgur.com/icZ8U.jpg - Can you elaborate a bit? Thank you.

Comment: look at the publish tab and then look at the options for click-once and see if you can't get it to generate an installer that includes the .net stuff for...

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you can specify dependencies in your setup project. Under the "Detected Dependencies" it should say "Microsoft .NET Framework". If you want to change the behavior, right click on your setup project and hit "Properties" and click the "Prerequisites" button. From there, you can choose things that should be installed before your application is, and how they are provided - whether the setup will download them from the internet or distribute them with your application.

Comment: Oh that's wonderful! I'll try this out, be right back. EDIT: OK, it seems to do what I'm looking for. I'm confused about what radiobutton option I'm supposed to use. http://imgur.com/z2GDw.jpg - I'm guessing this is what I have to do: Set it to "download prerequisites from the same location as my application" and have the .exe file from here in the same folder? http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5ad0459-cbcc-4b4f-97b6-fb17111cf544&displaylang=en  - Thanks so much for your help.

Comment: If you want the application to include the .NET Framework itself, use the "download prerequisites from the same location as my application". This makes your installer bigger, but doesn't require an internet connection. The "download from vendor site" keeps your installer smaller, but requires a internet connection. If you select "download prerequisites from the same location as my application", you'll see after you build the setup project that it puts the .NET Framework 4 Client Profile setup in a directory under "DotNetFX40Client".

Comment: That's brilliant, thanks a bunch. I'll test this out for sure.

Answer (score 3):

Is [this](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=e5ad0459-cbcc-4b4f-97b6-fb17111cf544&displaylang=en) what you're after?

> The Microsoft .NET Framework 4 Client Profile redistributable package installs the .NET Framework runtime and associated files that are required to run most client applications.